# Outlook 2003: Connect IMAP server with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, imap

Sometimes Outlook (2003) loses the connection to one or more IMAP server. With VBA scripts that are supposed to move mails to these mailboxes, for example, I get this error message:

"Runtime error '-972759285 (c604df0b)':
Connection to server is unavailable. Outlook must be online or connected to complete this operation."

I then first have to click on "File" - "Connect to [MAILBOX...]" to establish this connection manually.
I am looking for a VBA solution to automatically connect to multiple mailboxes (IMAP only), but I don't know what to look for in VBA references.

I tried this:

```
Sub MyTest()

    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = myNameSpace.Folders("C-Interessenten").Folders("Interessenten")
    
    Set myNameSpace = Nothing

End Sub
```

or this

```
Sub IsOLOffline()

'Determines whether Outlook is currently offline.
    
    Dim myOlApp     As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set myOlApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Debug.Print myNameSpace.Offline

End Sub
```

Thank you for an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that out of the box.

The `Offline` property of the `Namespace` class returns valid information only for an Exchange profile. It's not intended for non-Exchange account types such as POP3, IMAPI, and HTTP.

You may try to use [SyncObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobjects) property of the `Namespace` class. It returns a set of `SyncObject` objects representing the `Send/Receive groups` for a user.

The [OnError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject.onerror) event is fired when Microsoft Outlook encounters an error while synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send\Receive group. So, it could help with detecting such cases and then initiating a new sync.

```
Public WithEvents mySync As Outlook.SyncObject 
 
Sub Initialize_handler() 
 Set mySync = Application.Session.SyncObjects.Item(1) 
 mySync.Start 
 mySync.Stop 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub mySync_OnError(ByVal Code As Long, ByVal Description As String) 
 MsgBox "Unexpected sync error" & Code & ": " & Description 
End Sub
```

A Send\Receive group lets users configure different synchronization scenarios, selecting which folders and which filters apply.

Use the `Item` method to retrieve the `SyncObject` object from a `SyncObjects` object. Because the `Name` property is the default property of the `SyncObject` object, you can identify the group by name.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the food for thought. I have already experimented a bit by creating a separate group for each IMAP mailbox. Testing is taking a long time because the connections only break sporadically and I can't trigger the break manually. Nevertheless, I have more and more the impression that the `SyncObject` does not lead to a solution. Thanks anyway.
Is there perhaps the possibility to call the menu item "File" - "Connect to xxx" via vba, for example via `FindControl()`?